# Geting and seting fields using properties in C#

Tags: c#, .net, properties

Hi I have recently started to learn C# and have some questions regarding properties.
Let's say I have this statement:

```
private int minAge { get; set; }
```

Does this translate into this:

```
private int minAge

public int MinAge
{
    get { return this.minAge; }
    set { this.minAge = Convert.ToInt16(TextBox1.Text); } //this is what I would like                     to set the field to
}
```

Let's say that I have a button and when I press that button I need it to set the minAge field and after that return the data.How can I achieve this?

I tried this but it does not seem to work:

```
   minAge.get //to return data
   minAge.set =  Convert.ToInt16(TextBox1.Text); //to set the data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you just do is to public your property:

```
 public int minAge { get; set; }
```

Then you can use for get and set (implicitly):

```
 int age = minAge; //to return data
 minAge =  Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text); //to set the data
```

Comment: I tried doing it the way you said:  public int minAge { get; set; },  minAge = 10;int a = minAge.get; but I get an erorr that sais int does not contain a defininition for get

Comment: okk so in other words C# automaticly calls the get and set methods?I just need a confirmation on this to know if I udnerstand this right

Comment: @user1525474: yes, it is implicit and automatic :)

Answer (score 2):

You define your property inside the class and to get and set the property, you have to use class instance

```
YourClass objYourClass = new objYourClass;
int minAge= objYourClass.MinAge; //To get

objYourClass.MinAge =Convert.ToInt16(TextBox1.Text); //o set the property
```

Comment: hmmm so I have declare an object even if I am using it in the same class I declare it?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the properties via:

```
minAge = 10;
```

To retrieve the property you can do:

```
int age = minAge; // retrieves the age via the minAge property
```

Note this will have to be inside the `Class` this property is defined in.  If you are trying to set the value of minAge for an object you could do:

```
var obj = new YourClass(); 

obj.minAge = 100; // sets minAge to 100

int minAge = obj.minAge; // Assigns the minAge variable to that of `obj` minAge value.
```

The difference between

```
 public int minAge { get; set; }
```

And:

```
 private int minAge

public int MinAge
{
   get { return this.minAge; }
   set { this.minAge = Convert.ToInt16(TextBox1.Text); } //this is what I would like                     to set the field to
```

}

Is that MinAge uses a backing property `MinAge` which is no longer required if you are using the one of the latest versions of the .NET framework (4+).

Comment: so in other words when I set minAge = 10 and int age = minAge C# automaticly calls the properties get and set?

Answer (score 1):

the property's set and get are of the same type as the underline member...

```
private int minAge

public int MinAge
{
    get { return this.minAge; }
    set { this.minAge = value } //"value" is of type int
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set properties in C# you don't have to access the get and set, it's done automatically:

```
// Get
int age = this.MinAge;

// Set
this.MinAge = Convert.ToInt16(TextBox1.Text);
```

You can create properties like this:

```
private int _minAge

public int MinAge
{
    get { return _minAge; }
    set { _minAge = value; }
}
```

Or if you use .NET 3.5 or above you can simple use:

```
public int MinAge
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

The underling type is created automatically by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Actually

```
public int MinAge { get; set; }
```

is translated by compiler into something like

```
private int minAge_backfield;

public int MinAge 
{
get { return minAge__backingField;} 
set { minAge__backingField = value;}
}
```

This is called auto properties in C# and its usage its simple like

```
var val = MinAge;
```

or

```
MinAge = 10;
```

I have written a [blog post](http://www.adilmughal.com/2008/04/automatic-properties-in-c-2008-language.html) on this.